# When does one start to hit the 200 cap almost daily?

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

With [a (now deleted) previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408050/has-any-user-earned-the-legendary-badge-30k-reputation-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1#comment846167_408050) I discovered that there are people hitting the 200 rep/day almost every day, or at least more often than not.

Is there a statistic as to what is the reputation after which such a trend sets off?

(To be more precise, I mean a statistic of the average reputation after which there’s a spike in, say, the number of upvotes received per week, or something similar.)

Comment: I don't think it's based on *reputation*. Receiving upvotes is based on users finding your old posts and upvoting them. If you have very popular posts, you'd be getting more upvotes. So, it's based on whether the posts are highly visible, rather than your overall reputation.

Answer (score 32):

It varies massively. I hit the rep cap very-nearly-daily, and have done for several years, even if I'm not answering questions. [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035) has over twice as many answers as I have, but has *not* been regularly hitting the rep cap since he stopped posting regularly. (He's still getting rep, don't get me wrong - but not hitting the cap.) To be clear, this is in no way trying to make any claims about the *quality* of Gordon's answers - it's a reflection on the topics his answers cover.

Basically it depends on whether your old answers are still being found and voted on - and that depends on how search-friendly the questions are, and what topics they're on. (For example, I can easily imagine someone acquiring a large amount of reputation in a particular technology, then getting very little "on-going" reputation if that technology is superseded.)

Comment: Like you said, the technology is important here. Two of your strongest tags are Java and C# and those are place 3 and 4 of the tags with the most question, thus implying the most "traffic". SQL on the other hand, Gordons main Tag, is listed on 13th place, so significant fewer traffic/questions.

Comment: @Tom: Yup. I've added a sentence just to make it crystal clear that I'm not trying to criticize Gordon's answers :)

Comment: Your observation on passive rep is pretty solid. One thing I would like to add (or at least say explicitly) though, is new posts: if you get a couple hundred rep to please the system wrt. automatic rate limits, and start churning out tens of answers per day, it's pretty trivial to hit the rep cap daily, provided the answering spree continues. This is completely independent of rep.  However, finding enough high-quality questions to do that effectively is tricky these days, particularly on established/mainstream technologies where all the low-hanging fruit has been answered several hundred times

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh ... I didn't mean to imply that you criticized the quality of his answers by mentioning the traffic of the tags. I just agreed on your tech argument and tried to be a bit more specific about that.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I wasn't trying to imply that you were - just thought it might be worth clarifying, as your comment highlighted the cause really clearly :)

Answer (score 16):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer doesn't have historic reputation events for users so it is hard to exactly answer your question with the public data we have. Nevertheless I had some fun to create a query that might give some insight in how each of these extraordinary users hit the daily cap.

Instead of trying to find the tipping point I focused on the *almost daily* bit. So I asked my self: What is the count of the number of days between subsequent daily rep caps. Without doing the full/accurate reputation calculation (just a ballpark figure only based on what is available in the Votes tables)

This is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1593391) and this is the result today:

[image]

Based on this we confirm that Jon is a pretty consistent daily cap hitter, with not having a gap of over > 4 days not earning 200 rep.

We can see some runner-ups that are doing pretty well and these stats support the point Jon made in his  answer as well.

Now we know the users and the dates they hit the cap we can for a single user zoom in on which posts bring them those reputation caps.

So [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1593865?UserId=22656) shows for Jon Skeet the total votes received on rep-capped days and on how many days that post got a vote, aka it did contribute to the reaching the reputation cap.

Here is what it looks like today:

[image: counts and ratios for posts of Jon Skeet]

There are clearly posts that contribute multiple times on a single day to Jons' reputation cap days.

Let's see what [Martijn Pieters](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1593865?UserId=100297) stats look like:

[image: counts and ratios for posts of Martijn Pieters]

Notice how Martijn has a promising [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216000/why-is-faster-than-list/30216156#30216156) to help him hit the cap more regularly.

Finally let see what the stats for [Gordon Linoff](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1593865?UserId=1144035), an epic reputation collector though not by means of reaching the reputation as regularly as Jon or the others, looks like:

[image: counts and ratios for posts of Gordon Linoff]

The lower ratio is the sign that he lacks a post that leverages a consistent / guaranteed contribution to his daily reputation cap.

Now I leave it to others to analyze these example posts and draw conclusions from them.